Typedef for 2 dimensional array in C and access via a pointer
I create custom type for table (2 dimensional array):
typedef int table_t[4][2]; // 4 rows, 2 columns

Next, I declare table and pointer to the table:
table_t a = { { 10, 0 },    // my table
              { 20, 0 }, 
              { 30, 0 }, 
              { 40, 0 } };

table_t *b = &a;          // pointer to my table

Next, I try to print first column of the table:
    printf("%d\n", a[0][0]);    // var1. 
    printf("%d\n", a[1][0]);    // It's work    
    printf("%d\n", a[2][0]);
    printf("%d\n", a[3][0]);

It works. How can I get access to elements to the table over pointer to table_t?
I try to print first column of table over pointer:
    printf("%d\n", *b[0][0]);   // var2. 
    printf("%d\n", *b[1][0]);   // It's print true value only from *b[0][0] and
    printf("%d\n", *b[2][0]);   // some strange from other elements
    printf("%d\n", *b[3][0]);

Maybe I do something wrong? Suddenly for me next code works, but why the table has rotated? :
    printf("%d\n", *b[0][0]);   // var3
    printf("%d\n", *b[0][1]);   // Suddenly, it's work too.
    printf("%d\n", *b[0][2]);   
    printf("%d\n", *b[0][3]);

Godbolt demo: https://godbolt.org/z/7bb63vGxT

*b[x][y] ==> (*b)[x][y]

The [] operator groups more tightly than the unary * operator.  So *b[0][1] is equivalent to *(b[0][1]), which isn't what you want.  Instead, you want to dereference b first, as in (*b)[0][1].

b has type pointer to a table_t, hence you should access the table via *b, and since postfix operators have a higher priority than prefix operators, you must parenthesize *b before dereferencing the table elements:
void print_column_zero(table_t *b) {
    printf("%d\n", (*b)[0][0]);
    printf("%d\n", (*b)[1][0]);
    printf("%d\n", (*b)[2][0]);
    printf("%d\n", (*b)[3][0]);
}

[...]

    // passing a pointer to the table
    print_column_zero(&a);

Note that instead of using a pointer to table_t, you could write:
void print_column_zero(table_t b) {
    printf("%d\n", b[0][0]);
    printf("%d\n", b[1][0]);
    printf("%d\n", b[2][0]);
    printf("%d\n", b[3][0]);
}

[...]

    // passing a table, which decays to a pointer to its first element
    print_column_zero(a);

Since table_t is a typedef for an array, this would be equivalent to: void print_column_zero(int (*b)[2])... and print_column_zero(&a[0]), ie: a pointer to the table elements would be passed, just as for void print_column_zero(table_t *b) but with a type that does not require dereferencing. The generated code should be very similar if not identical.
Pointer to arrays are somewhat confusing and seldom used in practice. You might want to encapsulate your table in a structure instead:
typedef struct table_t {
    int table[4][2]; // 4 rows, 2 columns
} table_t;

table_t a = {{ { 10, 0 },    // my table
               { 20, 0 }, 
               { 30, 0 }, 
               { 40, 0 } }};

void print_column_zero(table_t *b) {
    printf("%d\n", b->table[0][0]);
    printf("%d\n", b->table[1][0]);
    printf("%d\n", b->table[2][0]);
    printf("%d\n", b->table[3][0]);
}

[...]

    printf("%d\n", a.table[0][0]);
    printf("%d\n", a.table[1][0]);
    printf("%d\n", a.table[2][0]);
    printf("%d\n", a.table[3][0]);

    print_column_zero(&a);    // same output

    table_t *b = &a;          // pointer to my table
    print_column_zero(b);     // same output again

This approach does not add any overhead compared to the previous ones, yet the struct encapsulation allows for related data to be added as may become useful and enables copying the table with a single assignment operation.

Thanks, You right. I made mistake with priorities of operations. And thanks for the advice - code with structure is more understandable.

Hiding arrays (or pointers) behind typedef isn't a great idea, since it makes the program harder to read and maintain. And bugs easier to write, as you noticed.
The issue is that [] has higher operator precedence than * dereferencing.

The actual type of b is int (*)[4][2].
So in case of *b[i][j], the first [i] dereferences the pointer
The second [j] gives us array number j with type int [2].
The * gives the first item in that array, since "array decay" means we get a pointer to the first item here.

So for example *b[0][1] would give the second array of type int [2] and * the first item, 20. Not as expected.
And the obvious solution would be to write (*b)[0][0].
A better solution would have been to get rid of the typedef and declare the pointer as int (*b)[2] = a;. This gets rid of the extra indirection as lets you type b[i][j].

(In C23 we could also somewhat cryptically have written typeof (*a)* b = a;, but that's just hard to read and understand so I don't recommend it.)

Or just auto b = a;

@tstanisl typeof (*a)* b = a; is type safe, auto b = a; is not and about as bad as writing void* b = a;. What if I meant to do &a or *a? The first example yields a compiler error then, the auto and void pointer versions just merrily carry on and now we have a hidden bug. Changing the meaning of auto was one of those royally stupid mistakes of C++, designed by people who have never worked with high integrity software design.

What is so type-unsafe about auto b=a?

@tstanisl I've meant to write a self-answered Q&A about that at one point. Maybe now is the time :) I've posted a question over at Codidact Why is the new auto keyword from C++11 or C23 dangerous? and I'll write an answer there too.

Thanks for the link. It is very interesting though I don't agree with some arguments. I must admit it got really surprised with const auto vs auto const difference. I've tried to test it in CLANG (see link ) but it looks that the type is char * const in both cases. It it  an expected behavior or a potential bug in CLANG?

@tstanisl Hmm actually that part could probably do with some proof reading. Either way we do expect to get a const char* but we aren't getting one. I'll see if I can come up with a better example.

@tstanisl I've edited the Codidact post to make it a slight bit less confrontal, since I might have mixed up this with some compiler extension or another. Will revisit when I have more time. Anyway, the issue that we can't mix auto with const correctness is also still a serious enough flaw to motivate a removal of auto from the language.
